# Is it correct to use the subjunctive in "the idea is that you be able to improve"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, subjunctive-mood

I don't know which of the following is correct:

1. "the idea is that you **be** able to improve…"
2. "the idea is that you **are** able to improve…"

I would personally use the second option (the first sounds incorrect to me!), but a colleague said she'd been taught to use "be" (the subjunctive).
Can someone give us a hand?

Is it appropriate to use the subjunctive form of "be" in this context?

Comment: More context is needed. In some cases, 'The idea is that you would then be able to improve' would work; in some,  'The idea is that you should then be able to improve'. loading's answer would work in some cases.

Comment: You're on the wrong site. What you want is [SE English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> the idea is that you *will be* able to improve

The first sentence looks wrong, and the second sentence has a different meaning.

Answer (score -3):

```
I am able to improve. 
She is able to improve. 
You are able to improve.
```

[Conjugate be](http://conjugation.io/english-conjugation-be)

The verb is *be*, the adjective is *able* and the infinitive is *to improve*.

Comment: For the life of me, I don't know why this was down voted. Next time leave a comment.

Comment: The question is asking if the subjunctive should be used. It isn't asking about the conjugation of "to be" in the indicative.

Comment: That's the wrong conjugation in the subjunctive: *It is essential that I be able to improve. It is essential that you be able to improve. It is essential that he be able to improve.*